# vscode. Использую Vim. После использования терминала в vscode, хочу при нажатии esc чтобы курсор переходил на старое место где раньше писал код?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Такая функция есть в webstorm - и эта почти единственная причина почему я не использую vscode. Как это исправить? Я к примеру пишу код, вызываю терминал горячими клавишами, что то вбиваю, нажимаю esc но курсор остается в терминале. Когда по логике терминал должен закрываться а курсор переходить на старое место.
И второй вопрос, он другой. Я к примеру создаю файл, пишу имя этого файла, и забываю как именно я должен назвать его, сварачиваю ide чтобы уточнить, а файл почему то принимает команду будто я нажал подтвердить и по итогу я имею уже котовый файл с именем который я еще не закончил. Приходится переименовывать что лишнее движение, опять же в webstorm с этим норм, но я хочу к vscode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё предельно просто. Вызов терминала

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `` ` ``

возврат нажимаешь также

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `` ` ``

только терминал закроется и Вы окажетесь в месте последнего редактирования

либо смените горячие клавиши на терминал добавив в `keybindings.json` следующее

```
{
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"
},
```

конечно `esc`, будет открывать и закрывать терминал, для очистки смотрите комбинации команд.

Можно посмотреть на такой [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611435/visual-studio-code-keybindings-running-two-or-more-commands-with-one-shortcut), только у меня не получилось посадить всё на `esc`

```
Settings.json

"macros": {
    "cleanAndCloseTerminal":[
      "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
      "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"
    ]
  }
```

и

```
keybindings.json

{
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "macros.cleanAndCloseTerminal"
}
```

Comment: Все так, но моя цель - esc. Фетишь мой чтоли) Но хочу чтобы на esc он закрывал терминал и удалял что было введено раньше. А так он просто сворачивает, но спасибо вам за ответ!

Comment: @ZhassulanAbishev Добавил в ответ ещё изысканий

Comment: вау спасибо вам! То что надо!